# Ping Issues using Thunderbolt to CAT

Tags: network, thunderbolt, ping

Is anyone having a higher than usual ping when using a thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter? Or maybe the thunderbolt adaptor has a known issue?

Found this thread, [Ping on Mavericks on late 2013 MacBook Pro slow and variable compared to Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110777/ping-on-mavericks-on-late-2013-macbook-pro-slow-and-variable-compared-to-windows)

but it doesn't look to cover hardwire connections.

Comment: Not really, but what are your numbers?

Comment: 30ms, having some issues when gaming.  I have a high bandwidth at 50mb but wondering if it's an issue of my MacBook Pro not having a dedicated Ethernet port.  I saw the post I mentioned in the question and hoped maybe it was a solution.

Comment: Did you Ping your router or a web site? What is your ping for Google.com

Comment: I have only used speedtest and pingtest and provided those results.  I am not sure how to ping check for something like Google.com.  Not sure if it's worth mentioning but am also using a apple time capsule router.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I checked ping time with google server and --- www.google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.066/17.942/22.067/2.154 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did the test using the ping command in terminal

For Google.com

```
Ping Google.com
```

The result for 2.5 GHz WiFi was:

> 20 packets transmitted, 19 packets received, 5.0% packet loss
>   round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 16.295/18.872/30.858/2.935 ms

with transmit rate of 130.

And for my 5 GHz WiFi:

15 packets transmitted, 15 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 17.451/19.066/21.444/1.157 ms

with transmit rate of 216.